# Finding the formula for a linear transformation on R^2

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to find the formula for a linear transformation from $T: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$

Given: $T(3, 4) = (-1,-2)$

How would I go on doing this?

Comment: Do you know how $T$ acts on a basis?

Comment: You have to supply one more value of $T$. The answer is not unique otherwise.

Comment: It can't be unique. But then the answer must contain arbitrary values a and b in the matrix